How do I change ownership of database objects after migration of postgresql database in azure?
I migrated existing single server postgresql database to flexible server, I am encountering the below error when setting ownership like so, ALTER TABLE schema.table OWNER TO comm_user;and I am logged in as server admin pgadmin

ERROR:  must be able to SET ROLE "comm_user" SQL state: 42501

This is confusing as I was able to set ownership before migration. I think MS has bug.

The solution is here, as described by Rafi Trad's response. You have to GRANT membership to that role for the admin user.

GRANT comm_user TO "your_pgadmin_account" WITH INHERIT FALSE;

ALTER TABLE my_schema.my_table OWNER TO comm_user;

(as recommended) REVOKE comm_user FROM "your_pgadmin_account";



Thanks for quick response, getting syntax error when issuing GRANT;

Did you expand on the 1 comment from Rafi's post for some reason it was omitted, GRANT new_role TO server_admin_user WITH INHERIT FALSE; 

Missed that, still getting error ERROR:  permission denied for schema x_migration_data SQL state: 42501

What permissions does this comm_user have??? Did you GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA AND/OR GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA?

Yes, I overlooked this one. It is working now, thanks you. It is confusing as this user had these permissions prior to migration. BOL wasn't clear on this.

You migrated from a single server to a flex server offering, although both are PaaS offerings, different servers where you had to create logins/roles I assume. Plus, I don't know what method you used to migrate but ownership can change too.
